# Nagios nrpe commands error out with asterisk

Tags: nagios, nrpe

Using nrpe command:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H [HOSTNAME] -c check_asterisk_version
```

Outputs: `Error getting version`

I have this line in my `nrpe.cfg`

```
command[check_asterisk_version]=/scripts/nagisk.pl -c version2
```

[Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nagisk/) is the script I am running

I also have similar issues with a [different asterisk plugin](http://www.it-slav.net/blogs/2009/02/13/asterisk-monitoring-with-nagios-or-op5-monitor/) as well

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is no nagisk check named "version2". Use this instead:

```
command[check_asterisk_version]=/scripts/nagisk.pl -c version
```

Try it manually by running `./nagisk.pl -c version` on your Asterisk server. You should see the Asterisk version as output.